# JavaScript - ES6 function does not work for some weird reason

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6

I am setting the below function in order to retrieve it after.
However, for some reason, it does not work:

```
constructor(private nativeStorage: NativeStorage) {
    // I am calling it this way:
    this.userId = 123;
    this.getItem("userId", this.userId);

   // If I replace the shortcut by the below it works fine

   /* this.nativeStorage.getItem("userId).then(
        data => this.userId = data,
        error => console.error(error)
    ); */
}

getItem(itemKey, itemValue) {
  return this.nativeStorage.getItem(itemKey).then(
    data => itemValue = data,
    error => console.error(error)
  );
}
```

I believe that I am missing something here, that's why it doesn't work

Comment: what do you expect this function `data => itemValue = data` to do?

Comment: What doen't work?

Comment: `this.nativeStorage.getItem(itemKey)` is a promise?
Try with `then` and `catch`

Comment: @Thomas assign `itemsValue` to `data`

Comment: `itemValue` is a local variable. Reassigning it has no effect outside of `getItem()`. Did you try to implicitely update `this.userId`?

Comment: @Thomas, no I didn't, `this.userId` is only one of the existing values that I want to pass inside `getItem()` function, so I can't replace it

Comment: So what did you expect to happen by reassigning `itemValue = data`. Or in other words: What should have happened and didn't? And how do you determine that it didn't happen? Maybe only your check is wrong and doesn't properly log the change.

Comment: @Thomas Good question. Basically, assigning `itemValue = data` should be translated to something like the following `this.userId = data`, in the current scenario is you try to do a `console.log` of `this.userId` inside `constructor()` you'll see nothing, only blank ! That the issue

Comment: This looks like TypeScript, not ES6...

Comment: @Badacadabra TypeScript is only a superset of JS, so the same concepts stay

Comment: @Folky.H: Not a subset, but a superset... :)

Comment: Then check out the answer by @ibrahimmahrir. JS doesn't support a similar feature. Besides that, this also has another flaw: `this.nativeStorage.getItem()` is async. You don't know when this update of `this.userId = data` will happen. And 100ms (wich you barely notice) is like hours for JS code. Unless you deal with the promise, whatever code epends on `this.userId` may still process the old value.

Comment: @Thomas Exactly. The asynchronous nature of `this.nativeStorage.getItem` is also a problem here.

Comment: To shorten this down: the constructor **can not work as you expect it to**. You can't have async constructors. Implement a factory function that does all the async stuff and returns a Promise of a built instance of this class. Maybe as a static function `createById()`? To do so, you'll also need to reference whatever there is in `this.nativeStorage` in that static function. Can't be more specific by only that snippet of your class.

Comment: I got your point clearly, but do you think that there is no solution to avoid that repetitive sequence of code in this particular case? I believe that there should be a solution!

Comment: That are two unrelated problens that just happen to be in the same piece of code. But due to the changes you have to make to solve the async problem, the problem of repetitiveness here will vanish.

Comment: @Thomas please check this link out, you may have a clearer idea about what I am trying to do: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/native-storage/

Answer (score 3):

You're assigning `data` to `itemValue` which is just a copy of `this.userId`. **JS doesn't support pass by reference** that could make that possible. Instead you can just use `itemKey` to assign to the class instance directly like this:

```
getItem(itemKey) {
    return this.nativeStorage.getItem(itemKey).then(
        data => this[itemKey] = data, // assign data to this[itemKey] which will be this.userId (in the example above)
        error => console.error(error)
    );
}
```

Comment: itemKey is a static value, I need to pass also, ItemValue

Comment: @Folky.H You're not using it so there will be no need to pass it. Plus `itemKey` is sufficient, if you want the value you can access it using `this[itemKey]`.

Comment: Basically, assigning `itemValue = data` should be translated to something like the following `this.userId = data`, in the current scenario if you try to do a `console.log` of this.userId inside `constructor()` you'll see nothing, only blank ! Got me?

Comment: @Folky.H that's due to the async nature of `this.nativeStorage.getItem()`. JS won't wait for the promise to resolve so it can log the updated value.

Comment: Assigning `itemValue = data` **is not** translated to `this.userId = data`. That would be pass-by-reference which is not supported.

Comment: All the mentioned resolutions are logical; however it didn't worked. The only working solution is setting the following inside the `constructor()` 
`this.nativeStorage.getItem("userId).then(
        data => this.userId = data,
        error => console.error(error)`

Comment: However, writing that multiple times inside the `constructor` is really stupid. Is there anyway to sort it out ?

Comment: @Folky.H No. This constructor can not work the way you intend it to; you can't have async constructors. Since this ain't related to this particular answer, let's continue the topic in the comments of the Question itself.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is not supporting call by reference. It's only by value arg passing. So values can be updated only by object references only.

Answer (score 0):

In reference to the part/comments where you can't have an async constructor and therefore I extract all the async parts into a factory.

I have no experience yet with ionic, so you should take the following as pseudocode:

```
import { NativeStorage } from '@ionic-native/native-storage';

function constructor(public userId: String){ }


//and the factory function
//don't know how exactly how to export stuff in that framework
function createById(userId){
    return NativeStorage.getItem('userId')
        .then(
            userId => new YourClass(userId)
            error => console.error(error)
        )
}
```

or in the case where you want to assign multiple properties:

```
//a utility to resolve with { key: Promise<value> } mappings + pretty much everything you throw at it.
//warning: doesn't resolve promises in nested structures (by design), 
//stuff like {key: { foo: Promise<value> }}
//ideally you'd put that in a seperate module since it can be handy in many places.
function resolve(obj){
    if(Array.isArray(obj)
        return Promise.all(obj);

    if(typeof obj === "function")
        return Promise.resolve().then(obj);

    if(!obj || typeof obj !== "object" || "then" in obj && typeof obj.then === "function")
        return Promise.resolve(obj);

    var keys = Object.keys(obj);
    return Promise.all( keys.map(k => obj[k]) )
        .then(values => combine(keys, values));
}

//takes two Arrays, a matching set of keys and values and combines that into an object.
function combine(keys, values){
    return keys.reduce((acc, key, index) => {
        acc[key] = values[index];
        return acc;
    }, {});
}

const assignTo = target => source => Object.assign(target, source);

//in this case we use assign all async values outside of the constructor
function constructor(){ 
    this.userId = null;
    this.userName = null;
}

function createById(userId){
    return resolve({
        userId: NativeStorage.getItem('userId'),
        userName: NativeStorage.getItem('userName'),
        //...
    }).then(
        assignTo( new YourClass() ),
        error => console.error(error)
    )
}
```

Or if this is still to much repetition for you:

```
//a utility to fetch multiple items at once 
function getItems(...keys){
    return Promise.all( keys.map( key => NativeStorage.getItem(key) ) )
        .then(values => combine(keys, values));
}

//and a quick test
getItems("userId", "userName", ...).then(console.log);

//or in the context of the last snippet:
getItems("userId", "userName", ...).then(assignTo( new YourClass() ));
```

Hope this helps shows you a different approach to your problems.